# What is the difference between touch focus and autofocus?

Tags: autofocus, focus, camera-basics, camera-settings

I have a cheap Chinese Android phone, a Landvo l200 based on MTK68XX chip. It claims to have a 13MP touch & autofocus camera. I wanted to know how this autofocus feature differs from touch focus internally. Functionally I know the difference. Is there a physical lens movement actually happenening or some emulation going on behind the scenes?

Comment: What *do* you think the difference is functionally?

Answer (score 3):

Touch focus just uses your touch to choose the area of contrast on which to base focus. The auto mode just decides that for itself. There's nothing physically different with the actual focus process.